# Save two clients data to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two clients who will be connecting to my server. I have the following code that sets up the server, and then clients would run the command

telnet localhost 3000 on their terminals. Now this part works

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net')
var listOfClients = []
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.write("Welcome to ROCK PAPER SCISSORS choose from the following \n")
  socket.write("[1] Rock \n")
  socket.write("[2] Paper \n")
  socket.write("[3] Scissors \n")
  listOfClients.push(socket)
  server.getConnections(function(error, count) {
    if (count == 2) {

      let p1 = listOfClients[0].on('data', function(data) {
        return data;

      });

      let p2 = listOfClients[1].on('data', function(data) {
        return data;

      });

      console.log(p1)
      console.log(p2)
    }
  });
});
```

then the clients choose 1 or 2 or 3 for rock/paper/scissors I want to save what they used in a variable , but the method

```
let p1 = listOfClients[0].on('data', function(data) {
  return data;
});
```

doesn't save the data into a variable and returns a lot of stuff that I don't understand. Any ideas on how to do this? I have the sockets in the list just need them save the clients input to a variable.

Comment: You should understand how readable streams works. Is impossible that you found that code in any website, nor documentation. Better read documentation and understand clearly what is happening.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Ok ill get on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS works using [events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).
According to the documentations:

> Much of the Node.js core API is built around an idiomatic asynchronous event-driven architecture in which certain kinds of objects (called "emitters") emit named events that cause Function objects ("listeners") to be called.

In your code, the `listOfClients[0].on('data'...` snippet of code, is actually creating a listener for the event 'data'.
In essence, you're telling the code to: Hey, can you keep listening to those and do something when it happens? 
In your code, you're telling it to 'do something when the client[0] send some data'.

So when you write:

```
const variableName = something.on('someEvent', function(data) {});
```

The variable `variableName` is in reality, receiving the result of the event listener and using a callback as second argument.
Let's write a quick function that has one argument as a callback:

```
function myFunction(data, callback) {
    callback("This is where you're trying to return the value");

    return 'this is the event listener return';
}

const myVar = myFunction('Anything you please', function(callbackResult) {
    console.log(`This is the callback: ${callbackResult}`);
});

console.log(`This is the var value: ${myVar}`);
```

Running the above code will output:

```
node v10.15.2 linux/amd64

This is the callback: This is where you're trying to return the value
This is the var value: this is the event listener return
```

One solution to your problem, is just assigning the data to a variable outside the event listener, like so:

```
const storeHere = [];

function myFunction(data, callback) {
    callback("This is where you're trying to return the value");

  return data;
}

const myVar = myFunction('Anything you please', function(callbackResult) {
    storeHere.push(callbackResult); // Store somewhere outside
});

console.log(`This is the externalVar value: ${storeHere}`);
console.log(`This is the var value: ${myVar}`);
```